# Hide select stacked bar text annotation in plotly.express

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-python

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1['x'] = ['Product A', 'Product B', 'Product C']
df1['z'] = ['T1','T1','T1']
df1['y'] = [20, 14, 23]

df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2['x'] = ['Product A', 'Product B', 'Product C']
df2['z'] = ['T2','T2','T2']
df2['y'] = [40, 10, 55]

df = df1.append(df2)

fig = px.bar(df,
            y="x",
            x="y",
            text='y',
            color='z',barmode='stack')
fig.show()
```

I would like to show the labels for only T1, keeping within `plotly.express` framework because of the ease of adding `facet_col` features.

Current results below. I would like to remove the bar labels for T2 (red) keeping only the labels for T1 values.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(text = []) if t.name not in ['T1'] else ())
```

And get:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1['x'] = ['Product A', 'Product B', 'Product C']
df1['z'] = ['T1','T1','T1']
df1['y'] = [20, 14, 23]

df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2['x'] = ['Product A', 'Product B', 'Product C']
df2['z'] = ['T2','T2','T2']
df2['y'] = [40, 10, 55]

df = df1.append(df2)

fig = px.bar(df,
            y="x",
            x="y",
            text='y',
            color='z',barmode='stack')
fig.show()


# fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: print(t))
fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(text = []) if t.name not in ['T1'] else ())
fig.show()
```